# Not retrieving UserControl from a placeholder control

Tags: asp.net

I have a `datagrid` with `dropdown`  template under  `.ascx page`. I load it on `placeholder` control on my `.aspx`   page by using:

```
Control c = Page.LoadControl("~/CreateChecklist/GridWithMultiDropdown.ascx"); 
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(c);
```

Now i am trying to read `datagrid` template white in under placeholder from .aspx page  but its show me the `"ctl00$palceholder$drodownlist"`  not taking as a control.

Please help me how can i retrieve this `datagrid` data under `placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

Discard your server side code, go to aspx page then register your control and then place ur control tag inside placeholder and bang, it will work :)

Solution:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="myControl" TagPrefix="myControl" %>


<html>
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phControl" runat="server">
    <myControl:myControl ID="ctrlControl" runat="server" />
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Regards

Ali Muhammad**

Comment: i already add .ascx control with my placeholder at .aspx page. But my problem is retrieving data from placeholder.

Comment: my code is :             foreach (Control cnt in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
            {
                if (cnt is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox attrLabel = (TextBox)cnt;
                    options += attrLabel.Text;
                }

                if (cnt is DropDownList)
                {
                    DropDownList attrDropDown = (DropDownList)cnt;
                    options += attrDropDown.Items[attrDropDown.SelectedIndex] + "; ";
                }
            }